# What happened to the Project Facets pane in newer versions of Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, antlr, antlr4

My university has been using Eclipse for one of my modules along with the antlr4 plugin which works fine but only on the earlier version of eclipse which i cannot find online. In Eclipse 2019 i cannot find a project facets pane in the properties window when opened after right clicking on the package in the explorer window.

Have faceted project features been removed from the newer versions of Eclipse and if not then does anyone know where i need to go to convert my project to faceted form?

I've tried looking through all of the properties in the properties window and i have reinstalled the Antlr plugin.

I expected to find a "Project Facets" pane in the properties window of my package.

Comment: As far as I know, project facets are only included in the [_Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers_](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2019-03/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-developers) package, not in the other packages (e.g. not in the _Eclipse IDE for Java Developers_, etc.).

Comment: Which facet were you looking for? You should be able to add the necessary features to your existing installation.